# Recursive Scheduling algorithm does not work correctly Python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion, scheduling

I've created a recursive scheduling algorithm that takes an array of Event objects which hold a start-time and end-time. These times are randomly generated and start-time is always less than end time. The time is a number between 0-24 (24 hours in a day, 24 == 0)

Here is the code to the random event array generator:

```
def randomEventArray(s):
    e = []
    rand1 = 0
    rand2 = 0
    for i in range(s):
        rand1 = random.randint(0,21)
        rand2 = random.randint(rand1+1,23)
        e.append(Event(rand1,rand2))
    return e
```

Here is the code for the Event object:

```
class Event:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.startTime = start
        self.endTime = end
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __str__(self):
        return (str([self.startTime,self.endTime]))
```

Now here comes the part which is causing issue. I've created a piece of code that recursively goes through a generated array of events, and lists the most events that can be held in a single 24 hours. No event should overlap.

Here is the recursive greedy algorithm created:

```
def scheduleGD2(E):
    events = []
    scheduleRecGD2(E,0,0, events)

    return events[:]

def scheduleRecGD2(E, eventPos, startTime,events):

    while eventPos < len(E) and E[eventPos].startTime < startTime:

        eventPos += 1
    if eventPos == len(E):
        return []
    minEndPos = eventPos
    for i in range(eventPos+1, len(E)):
        if E[i].endTime < E[minEndPos].endTime:
            minEndPos = i
    events.append(E[minEndPos])
    return scheduleRecGD2(E, minEndPos+1, E[minEndPos].endTime, events)

E = randomEventArray(20)
print(scheduleGD2(E))
```

The expected output of this algorithm is an array with the most events that can simultaneously occur in a single 24 hours without overlapping. e.g.

```
[[0, 1], [1, 3], [4, 8], [9, 17], [17, 24]]
```

However, I'm receiving the following output:

```
[[0, 1], [12, 16], [12, 16], [5, 17], [21, 22]]
```

Which clearly shows Arr[2] overlapping with Arr[1] (Arr[2].StartTime (12) < Arr[1].EndTime [16]) which should not be happening.

What is wrong and why this is happening?

Comment: You left out some critical dependencies.  I can intuit the `random` package easily, but I have no idea what `event` system you're using.

Comment: Sorry @prune, it was a custom built object. I will add this code in now

Comment: If it's custom-built, it's almost certainly not part of a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Among other things, please replace your random initialization routine with a particular test case that fails.  Also include your debugging traces.

Comment: @Prune I've added the code for this object which should now mean it follows that example as all dependencies are listed

Answer (score 1):

I instrumented your code for debugging, including replacing the Events package with simple pair tuples.

```
def scheduleRecGD2(E, eventPos, startTime, events):
    print("ENTER Rec", "eventPos", eventPos, "\tstartTime", startTime, "\n\tevents", events)

    while eventPos < len(E) and E[eventPos][0] < startTime:
        eventPos += 1

    if eventPos == len(E):
        return []

    minEndPos = eventPos
    print("\tFIRST: minEndPos", minEndPos, E[minEndPos])

    for i in range(eventPos+1, len(E)):
        if E[i][1] < E[minEndPos][1]:
            minEndPos = i 

    events.append(E[minEndPos])
    print("\tTRACE: minEndPos", minEndPos, E[minEndPos])

    return scheduleRecGD2(E, minEndPos+1, E[minEndPos][1], events)

# Main program
E = randomEventArray(8)
print(E)
print(scheduleGD2(E))
```

Output:

```
[(15, 20), (4, 7), (17, 20), (18, 23), (2, 7), (8, 23), (15, 23), (18, 20)]
ENTER Rec eventPos 0    startTime 0 
    events []
    FIRST: minEndPos 0 (15, 20)
    TRACE: minEndPos 1 (4, 7)
ENTER Rec eventPos 2    startTime 7 
    events [(4, 7)]
    FIRST: minEndPos 2 (17, 20)
    TRACE: minEndPos 4 (2, 7)
ENTER Rec eventPos 5    startTime 7 
    events [(4, 7), (2, 7)]
    FIRST: minEndPos 5 (8, 23)
    TRACE: minEndPos 7 (18, 20)
ENTER Rec eventPos 8    startTime 20 
    events [(4, 7), (2, 7), (18, 20)]
[(4, 7), (2, 7), (18, 20)]
```

---

**ANALYSIS**

Your algorithm trips over itself more than once.  Most of all, when you enter the routine a second time, you find the first record with an acceptable start time, and take its ending time as the "figure to beat".  From then on, you entirely ignore the start time given in the call, and the start times of the remaining events, looking *only* for something that beats the end time of a relative arbitrary interval.

You continue through the list this way, changing the given start time somewhat haphazardly, until you reach the end of the list.

---

**REPAIR**

Follow the many solutions available on line: First, sort your list in order of ending time, then start time.  Now it's a simple matter to walk through your list, finding the first available **start** time that is (a) later in the list than the most recently added tuple; (b) no less than the current end time.

Given the availability of solutions, I'll leave this to as an exercise for the student.  Start with the simple change in the randomization routine:

```
return sorted(e)
```